# PHP Shopify App redirect_uri "Oauth error invalid_request: The redirect_uri is not whitelisted" Issue

Tags: php, shopify, shopify-app, redirect-uri

I am facing an issue where the app works fine in local environment. However, when I deployed the shopify app on fly.io, I started facing an issue:

"Oauth error invalid_request: The redirect_uri is not whitelisted"

I have created an endpoint which takes shopname as parameter and I use that to install my public application on any store. It should work as the app is public and deployed on Fly.io

**Details of the endpoint:**

```
Route::get('/api/install/clipjoy', function (Request $request) {
    $shop = Utils::sanitizeShopDomain($request->query('shop'));
    $encodedRedirect = urlencode("https://clipjoy.fly.dev/api/shopify/redirect");
    header("Location: "."https://$shop/admin/oauth/authorize?client_id=$client_id&scope=write_products,read_orders,write_publications,read_publications,read_themes&redirect_uri=$encodedRedirect");
    exit();
});
```

I call installApp function on the /api/shopify/redirect hit.

**Detail of /api/shopify/redirect endpoint:**

```
public function installApp(Request $request)
    {
        $response = Http::post('https://'.$request->get('shop').'/admin/oauth/access_token?client_id=$client_id&client_secret=$client_secret='.$request->get('code'));
        return redirect(Utils::getEmbeddedAppUrl($request->query("host", null)));
    }
```

client_id and client_secret keys are placed correctly and verified already. I have added /api/shopify/redirect as well in the Allowed redirection URL(s). However, after the user app permission approval screen, the app home page shows up for a couple of seconds and then "Oauth error invalid_request: The redirect_uri is not whitelisted" issue occurs. When I see the network calls, I can see I get 400 error on /admin/oauth/authorize call. In addition to this, in the call redirect_uri updates to "https://not_defined/api/auth/callback".

[image: App URLs]

Comment: is this `https://clipjoy.fly.dev/api/shopify/redirect` URL is added into app settings for callback?

Comment: I have updated the description and added the image of all URLs. Please can you check if there is any issue ?

Answer (score -1):

Have you added the fly.io app URL to the Shopify application "Allowed redirection URL(s)" inside the App Setup?

Comment: I have updated the description and added the image of all URLs. Please can you check if there is any issue ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).